# Format database query result for email

Tags: mysql, email, powershell-2.0

I have a module that I use to run MySQL Queries. Normally it is just used to update the database, and for this it works fine. But now I need to get a result and return it by email.

My Module ends with:

```psh
return $dataSet.Tables["data"]
```

I can display this resultset on screen using

```psh
$result1 | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

But when I try to add it to my email it doesn't work.

I have tried various options, and

```psh
$body = ($result1 | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String)
```

comes the closest, but doesn't align any of the columns and headers.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns probably look misaligned, because most GUI mail clients use proportional fonts. For aligned columns you need the text displayed with a monospace font, or as an HTML table. You can transform your results into such a table with the [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx) cmdlet:

```psh
$htmlbody = $result1 | ConvertTo-Html
Send-MailMessage ... -Body $htmlbody -BodyAsHtml
```

In my test the conversion yielded some undesired columns from hidden properties, so you may need to select specific properties from `$result1`.

If you also want other custom text in the HTML body you can convert the table to just an HTML fragment (with nothing but the table in HTML format) and insert that into a larger HTML string:

```psh
$htmltemplate = @"
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<p>{0}</p>
{1}
</body>
</html>
"@

$table = $result1 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

$htmlbody = $htmltemplate -f 'my custom text', $table
Send-MailMessage ... -Body $htmlbody -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: that's great cheers. I see what you mean about the undesired columns though. It looks like it should work.